# How to put the content fill in the middle of the two tabbar

Tags: reactjs, native, tabview

I use react native to make app in android. and I use react-native-scrollable-tab-view, when I use two tabbar in the view .one is on top, the other is in bottom.But when I click one only display half screen. I want got the full screen. Thank you for your help!!
currently:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlZ6c.png)

I want to get:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaETj.png)

bellow is my code:

render(){
        return (

```
            <ScrollableTabView  

                renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBar 
                                        backgroundColor='#61b754' 

                                        style={styles.top}
                                         />}
                tabBarUnderlineColor='#fbc14a'
                tabBarActiveTextColor='#ffffff'
                tabBarInactiveTextColor='#ecf0f2'
                scrollWithoutAnimation={true}
                tabBarTextStyle={styles.navText}
            >               
                <View1 style={styles.navText} tabLabel="菜单1" />
                <View2 tabLabel="菜单2" />
                <View3 tabLabel="菜单3" />

            </ScrollableTabView>


            <ScrollableTabView  
                renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBar 
                                        backgroundColor='#61b754' 

                                        style={styles.top}
                                         />}
                tabBarUnderlineColor='#fbc14a'
                tabBarActiveTextColor='#ffffff'
                tabBarInactiveTextColor='#ecf0f2'
                scrollWithoutAnimation={true}
                tabBarTextStyle={styles.navText}

                tabBarPosition='bottom'
            >               


  <View5 tabLabel="菜单5" />
                <View6 tabLabel="菜单6" />
            </ScrollableTabView>
        </View>
    )
}
```